# Storing a list of objects in GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I need to store some data that looks a little like this:

```
xyz 123
abc 456
hij 678
rer 838
```

Now I would just store it as a traditional string and integer model, and put in the datastore. But the data changes regularly, and is ONLY relevant when looked at as a COLLECTION. So it needs to be store as either a list of lists, or a list of objects, both of which can't really be done without pickling as far as I know. Can anyone help? Even storing it as a text file may work :S

Edit: I was a litle vague on details it seems.

I am sampling some data from an external source (scraping via BeautifulSoup/http2lib if it matters). This data then needs to be stored, as a whole, since it will be plotted on a graph. The data changes (but not often - perhaps once a week). Since the dataset is so simple (literally what you see above, 1 string field, and 1 integer) I figured it's easier to store them as a list of lists, then actually store them in a model. I have a feeling I have skipped over an even easier solution by concentrating too much on the fact the data needs to be stored together as one large lump.

I will be storing 500+ of these bits of data as a group, at once.

Comment: Could you add some more details of your data?xyz can change?

Comment: How big is the dataset? How often does it change? Is all the data one huge collection that needs to be loaded at once, or do you load subsets? Do you need to be able to index it?

Comment: I'm not sure that that the dataset is simple is a reason not to use a model.  Nick's questions above will definitely be relevant, but why not just create a simple model with two properties?  That way it can be indexed and queried.  And if you need to group them together, or start storing more data, you can simply add another property to your model, rather than dealing with lists of lists.

Comment: If I have 500 of these two property models, surely that's way too expensive in terms of write operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just store them as *two separate lists* and only worry about combing them when you actually access them. Something like this:

```
class MyModel(db.Model):
    my_strings = db.StringListProperty()
    my_ints = db.ListProperty(int)

    def get_data(self):
        return zip(self.my_strings, self.my_ints)

    def set_data(self, data):
        self.my_strings = [element[0] for element in data]
        self.my_ints = [element[1] for element in data]

    data = property(get_data, set_data)
```

That way, you can just do something like

```
entity = MyModel()
entity.data = [("xyz", 123), ("abc", 456), ("hij", 678)]
entity.put()

# ...

for string_value, int_value in entity.data:
    # do something
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's really just a list of tuples / two "columns", could you just use an alternating list and a ListProperty?  This would be fine if the data had a consistent dimension, was small, and didn't require indexing.

e.g. To encode the example you gave in a list do:

```
# i forget if mixed types are allowed, but you get the idea.
["xyz", 123, "abc", 456, "hij", 678, "rer", 838]
```

Comment: Yeah this was the first idea that popped into my head, but I am worried about bizarre indexing problems further down the track.